# Validate single validation groups step by step in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I have three sections of a form that are contained in jquery tabs.  I want to have each tab have it's own validator on it so that if there are validation errors on that form, it is easy to see which forms the user needs to re-do.  The problem I am running into is that when I try something like this:

```
private void ValidateTabOne()
{
    Page.Validate("t1");
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        cvt1.IsValid = false;
}

private void ValidateTabTwo()
{
    Page.Validate("t2");
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        cvt2.IsValid = false;
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateTabOne();
    ValidateTabTwo();

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
       //do the save
    }
}
```

cvt2 will always be invalid if anything in the t1 group is invalid (regardless of if t2 group is valid or not) because I Validate("t1") first.

I'd still like a way to do this in the code behind.  How can I validate a single group at a time, or "reset" the validation to exclude the previous groups in the Page.IsValid check?

I know that worst case I can write a huge statement to check each validator for IsValid but would much rather use the validation groups.

Comment: May be you can send an ID of tab in post-back so you'll know which group you should validate in your btnSave_Click handler.

Comment: This is a good idea if I save each tab individually. Unfortunately I am wanting to save all the tabs at once.  Because of this, it would still validate each tab in order (as above) and not validate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this for now is to use Page.GetValidators as such:

```
foreach (IValidator v in Page.GetValidators("t1"))
{
    if (!v.IsValid)
    {
        cvt1.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
}
cvt1.IsValid = true;
```

Beforehand I do my custom validation, this just checks to make sure all the required validation is already accounted for.